# Vimeo API filter videos by duration

Tags: api, vimeo, vimeo-api

Following what's written in the official Vimeo API forum here 
[Filtering search results](https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:284614#comment_15396186)

I'm trying to get all StaffPicks channel videos with duration less than 30 secs. I used the following request:

> https://api.vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/videos/?&filter=duration&max_duration=0:0:30

I also tried other filters like:

> filter=upload_date,CC&filter_upload_date=day

but results do not take into account the filters.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received an answer from Vimeo Staff:

> Filtering by duration isn't possible on that endpoint:
>   developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/channels#GET/channels/{channel_id}/videos
>
> That said, I'll take this feedback and pass it along to our API team
>   for consideration!